# How to concat column values in SQL based on another column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like below which demonstrates attributes of product:

[image]

This is the query that I am using for the result above:

```
SELECT wp.id, wp.post_title, tt.taxonomy, t.name
FROM wp_posts wp 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON wp.ID = r.object_id 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy like 'pa_%'
```

and now I want to concat values of `name` where the `taxonomy` is same. So I changed query by adding `group_concat`:

```
SELECT wp.id, wp.post_title, tt.taxonomy, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name)
FROM wp_posts wp 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON wp.ID = r.object_id 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy like 'pa_%'
```

It ended up like below:

[image]

As you see the result is not correct which means it takes all values where i want only the same `taxonomy`

How I can achieve this by concatenating proper values with related taxonomy?

Comment: Your query with `GROUP_CONCAT()` should not work because the you have mixed unaggregated columns and aggregation expressions in a query with no `GROUP BY`.  Sadly, MySQL used to support this syntax.  Happily, this has been fixed and such a query has generated an error for several years with the default database settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is aggregation -- because you want one row per group in the result set.  You also need a way to aggregate strings, which MySQL provides in the form of `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT wp.id, wp.post_title, tt.taxonomy,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.name)
FROM wp_posts wp JOIn
     wp_term_relationships r
     ON wp.ID = r.object_id JOIn
     wp_term_taxonomy tt
     ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id  JOin
     wp_terms t
     ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy like 'pa_%'
GROUP BY wp.id, wp.post_title, tt.taxonomy;
```

Note that the unaggregated columns are in the `GROUP BY`.